# How to use Azure service bus topics & Subscriptions to load balance messages

Tags: load-balancing, subscription, azure-servicebus-queues

In reading many MSDN pages about the Azure Service Bus, it alludes to the ability to set up a "Load Balancing" pattern with the "Topic/Subscription" model, but never says how this is done.

My question is, is this possible. Essentially, we are looking to create Topics that would have a possible n number of subscribers that could be dynamically ramped up and down, based upon incoming load. So, it would not be using the traditional "multicast" pattern but round robining the messages to the subscribers. The reason we want to use this pattern is that we want to take advantage of the rules and filtering that reside in the Topics and Subscriptions, while allowing for dynamic scaling.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that you can scale up the number of receivers, where the receivers all read from the same subscription - each message will only be processed once, by one receiver.

Comment: Ahh, so the "multicast" behavior is not the default? My previous understanding of pub/sub was as a "multicasting" model, but, if the "load balancing" model is the default then good news for me, thanks.